# C++ declare and initialize const array

Tags: arrays, qt, initialization, constants

I am wondering about the proper way to declare a constant array in Qt.

This is my header file:

```
 class Index
 {
  private:
      const double indexArrayPaxZoneA[33];
 };
```

And this is my constructor:

```
 #include "Index.h"


 Index::Index()
   : indexArrayPaxZoneA { 0, 0.6, 1.6, 2.45, 3.3, 4.1, 4.9, 5.7, 6.5, 7.3, 8.1, 8.95, 9.8,
       10.6, 11.4, 12.2, 13.0, 13.85, 14.7, 15.5, 16.3, 17.1, 17.9, 18.75, 19.6,
       20.4, 21.2, 22.0, 22.8, 23.1, 23.4, 24.2, 25.0 },
  CGDEFAULT(504)
  {

  }
```

This constructor works fine in QtCretaor Windows but gives me an error in Mac:

```
  expected '('
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe your compiler on Mac is outdated and does not support c++11 and it's initializer list.

Comment: I use clang 64-bit. I use the array in several functions. So, if this is the case, then I will need to initialize it in each function? I do not think it allows initializing in the header file. Thank you!

Comment: Try to append `CONFIG+=c++11` into your `.pro` file. Your code worked fine for me then